# javascript - reading local text file - charset issue

Tags: javascript, file, encoding, filereader

I am reading local text file using input-type-file and FileReader.readAsText(). The problem arises when the local text file contains characters like **Ü**. In that case it is converted to **ï¿**. Of course I can set encoding manually to **iso8859-1** as a parameter of FileReader.readAsText(File, encoding) but the thing is that I have no clue what kind of encoding user has set on his side.

My question is whether there is an option to determine encoding on client machine ?

Best regards 
kkris1983

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to analyze the raw binaries of the text file to have a best guess at what the encoding is. There isn't any libraries for this in javascript AFAIK but you could port one from other languages.

Since that isn't very robust, you should also provide a manual override like `Characters not showing correctly? Change encoding:`

You can also have smart defaults, for example ISO-8859-1 if you detect it's western windows machine.